# Clone DataTable from One Dataset to DataTable of Other DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, merge, dataset

I am trying to clone Datable from one dataset to datatable from other Dataset, but it does not work.

```
Dataset ds = new Dataset();

 ds.Tables.Add("key");
 ds.Table["key"] = cust.Tables[0].Clone(); // This line is not working
```

Above code gives below error

```
Property or indexer 'System.Data.DataTableCollection.this[int]' cannot be assigned to — it's read only
```

cust is also a Dataset. Can someone help me resolve this

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Dataset, but it does not work. how?

Comment: @AjayPandya It gives error Property or indexer 'System.Data.DataTableCollection.this[int]' cannot be assigned to — it's read only

Comment: @Serv Please see above comment

Comment: I forgot to submit the answer. Just kept the tab open. Basically you forgot the add `(` and `)` around your `ds.Tables[0]` and you have to use `.Add()`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is similar to this:

> Property or indexer 'System.Data.DataTableCollection.this[int]' cannot
>   be assigned to -- it is read only

You are doing it right once, and then you are doing it wrong in the line after.
The error is telling you, that `cust.Tables[0]` is read only. You cannot assign any values to it, so you have to use the `Add()` method:

```
DataSet cust = new DataSet(); // create source DataSet
cust.Tables.Add("sourceTable"); //add table to source

DataSet ds = new DataSet(); // create target DataSet
ds.Tables.Add((cust.Tables[0]).Clone()); //clone source table
(ds.Tables[0]).TableName = "keys"; // assign name
```

You need to wrap `ds.Tables[indexer]` in paranthesis `()` so the compiler treats it as a datatable.

You should assign a `DataTable` variable to keep the readability:

```
var sourceTable = cust.Tables[0];
/* ... */
ds.Tables.Add(sourceTable.Clone());
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks a lot.